# DDMathParser 3.0.0 with CocoaPods

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, ddmathparser

Hey there and Merry Xmas,

I would like to add the DDMathParser to my Swift 3 project using the latest CocoaPods version. The problem is I only get DDMathParser 2.0.0 installed. What do I miss?

my podfile is:

```
platform :osx, '10.11'
target 'DDTest02' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'DDMathParser', :git => 'https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser.git'
```

When I try using:

```
pod 'DDMathParser', :git => 'https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser.git', :branch => 'swift-3.0'
```

It throws an error `warning: Could not find remote branch swift-3.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch swift-3.0 not found in upstream origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDMathParser author here...

There is no `swift-3.0` branch, so I'm not sure why you're trying that. Try specifying the `3.0.0` tag using:

```
pod 'DDMathParser', :git => 'https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser.git', :tag ⇒ '3.0.0'
```

Comment: Using the `:tag...` worked out successfully. Thank you very much for the quick answer. I've just seen your package update to Swift 3.0 and mistakenly assumed that there is a `swift-3.0` branch available.